# Starting a literary magazine

Tags: magazines, community, reader-engagement

Because of the corona outbreak, I'm stuck at home (as I'm sure lots of you are) and I decided to start a nonprofit online literary magazine dedicated to providing a platform for marginalized voices. However, I'm not completely sure how to establish a reader base and also encourage submissions for issues. Does anybody have any ideas/tips?

Comment: do you have a website for your project up yet?

Comment: @FightFireWithFire yup!

Answer (score 1):

If you have an existing social media following you could start there to promote it and ask everyone to get the word out.

A prime way would be to reach out to other small literary journals and strike up a dialog, and see if you can ally with them in some way that they would promote your submissions. Writers like to write and be seen, so reaching out might be effective - especially right now!

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what we did and it seems to be working so far!